# Jmeter how to make http request to service

Tags: apache, jmeter

I need to simulate creating users for my web service. The HTTP call to make to add a user in the service would be something like:

```
http://localhost:7555/test/createUser?usr=nick
```

So in Jmeter I created a thread group of 10 and set HTTP Request Default as:

```
server name: localhost
port number: 7555
path:        /test
```

and then I created a HTTP Request  under sample and put `/createUser` under its path and added parameters with name `usr` and value `nick`. When I run it, it does not seem to be calling my server to add `nick` to the user list 10 times. What am I doing wrong? How could I check whats the URL it called?

Answer (score 0):

> > How could I check whats the URL it called?

First add a Listener, for example View Results in Tree.

Second, enable log viewer in JMeter GUI, go to Options -> LogViewer.

Then in the View Results Tree node you can see the actual requests, while the log view will indicate if there was an exception.

[image]

Here is an example run of the test with my [JMX File](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/15314).

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Request Defaults config element will populate **default** values if they **are not specified** in the HTTP Request

So you have 2 options:

1. Use `/test/createUser` path in the HTTP Request Defaults
2. Use `/test/createUser` path in the HTTP Request Sampler

When you enter something in the Path input of the HTTP Request Sampler it automatically overrides default value.

See [Why It's SO Important To Use JMeter's HTTP Request Defaults](https://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults) for more detailed explanation.

Also double check HTTP Request Method, in the majority of cases user is created with HTTP POST.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. Is there a way to auto populate parameter values? moreover, I need to simulate the creation of 50 unique users so if my threads is 50, i need 50 unique parameters?